# Ok to show iAd beneath Tab Bar?

Tags: iphone, placement, advertisement, tab-bar

Would it be acceptable in an iPhone app to show the iAd underneath the bottom tab bar? I know that this is not ideal, but for programming reasons I find that it may be necessary. Does this impact the user experience in a significant way?

Comment: Have you got a mockup / screenshot to illustrate this layout? A picture speaks 1,000 words.

Comment: No I don't have one, I'm sorry. If I can post one I will. But basically imagine the Facebook app (tabbed) with a banner ad under the tab bar at the bottom of the screen on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Well I suspect placing an ad bar in a location traditionally reserved for navigation means you will get a lot more accidental clicks on the ad bar.

If that is your intention, it's certainly a dark pattern. If you want to provide a good UX then I would recommend against it.

Comment: No, that is not my intention at all. It is rather technically complicated, but my application is for both iPhone and iPad and involves a UISplitViewController, a UITabbarController, and iAd. I am just having the most impossible time laying out the three of these things in a way that will work for both iPhone and iPad and this is the best way that I can think of.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the BannerViewController (iAd) is a container view controller and not just a view that gets plopped onto a screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only bad UX as Devin stated, this also (most likely) won't be accepted by Apple. So the best thing to do for you is ask on stackoverflow or any other coding site for some implementation help.

See the App Store Review Guidelines

> Apps that artificially increase the number of impressions or click-throughs of ads will be rejected

or

> Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines

or

> Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Good luck!

Comment: Please also take some time to review the HIG for iOS. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/